# Best website to get freelancer work

Tags: freelance-websites

I am a professional and experienced developer with 7 years experience.

I bid on Upwork and freelancer regularly but did not get any response from any clients.

Is there any other good website to get freelance work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will speak strictly statistically without touching the quality of those sites.

If there are 10k and more designers that succeeded on sites like Upwork, Freelancer,... I do not see reason why you should search something else.

Instead, try to analyze why you did not get any job. It could be your price OR your English OR lastly quality of your design. Good think is that people of all quality level succeed on such sites, so you should probably set your price better.

So try this:

1. You see cool job and you bid
2. You do not get the job
3. DO NOT stop here. Take this task and make it for yourself and post it on places like Behance and other

Working this way you will quickly build good portfolio of samples which you can show to your clients. I am positive that 99,99% of clients wants to see some previous works when they hire a designer. Working this way, you do not need to get actually hired to build portfolio - isn't it better to build your portfolio then only big and do nothing?!

Answer (score 0):

well, I started with fiverr and I was successful from there, nevertheless, I suggest you follow the advice given by @Peter